# What does `nowritebackup` actually do?

Tags: backup

I hear somewhere that if `backup` is disabled and `writebackup` is enabled, Vim will create backup files for the duration of the edit session and will delete these backup files afterward. However, even with these settings, i.e.

```
set nobackup
set writebackup " Enabled!
set noswapfile
set noundofile
```

I don't see any additional files created.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for exactly? `nobackup` with `writebackup` means that the backup file is immediately deleted after a successful write.

Comment: @ZeroKnight So, as I understand the information [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-the-vi/9780596529833/ch15s05.html) about `nowritebackup` is not correct?

Comment: The line about backup files persisting until the session ends is incorrect. They're either transient or kept until you delete them, depending on the `backup` setting. Take a look at `:h backup-table`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`backup` and `writebackup` are two separate yet intertwined options; they are essentially two halves of the same whole. I think the easiest way to explain these two options is by detailing what happens when you attempt to overwrite a file with some combination of these options.

#### Scenario Breakdown

Assume you have an existing file `foo.txt`. You make some changes to it (beyond just appending to it) and issue a `:write` command...

If either `backup` or `writebackup` (or both) are enabled, then *before* writing the file, Vim will create a backup (location depends on the `backupdir` setting). Afterwards, Vim will attempt to write the original file. At this point, behavior depends on the `backup` setting:

- If `nobackup`, then the backup file is **immediately deleted** upon successfully writing the original file.
- If `backup`, then the backup file is **kept** afterwards and will be overwritten on future backups.

And that's it; behavior really depends on the `backup` setting. It should be noted that `backup` will override `writebackup` in the case that the former is enabled and the latter is disabled, e.g. `:set backup nowritebackup`. In other words, it is identical to `:set backup writebackup`.

This table from [`:h backup-table`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#backup-table) outlines the same thing:

```
                            *backup-table*
'backup' 'writebackup'  action
   off       off    no backup made
   off       on     backup current file, deleted afterwards (default)
   on        off    delete old backup, backup current file
   on        on     delete old backup, backup current file
```

---

#### Regarding the option names

You may be thinking that the names of these options should be swapped, as each option's name seems to describe the other's more accurately. I originally held this same opinion, but I'm going to mirror KRyan's insightful comment here:

> To help understand the naming convention, consider this: `backup` always produces a backup, while `writebackup` produces a backup *during a write procedure*. In other words, *write* is not used as a verb, but as an adjective describing the type of backup you’re enabling.

Comment: To help understand the naming convention, consider this: `backup` always produces a backup, while `writebackup` produces a backup *during a write procedure*. In other words, *write* is not used as a verb, but as an adjective describing the type of backup you’re enabling.

Comment: "*write* is not used as a verb, but as an adjective". That's brilliant.

Comment: Glad you like it! Feel free to incorporate it into your answer if you wish.

Answer (score 4):

As @ZeroKnight said with `:set nobackup writebackup` the backup file will be used during `:write` but will be deleted afterwards.  The official documentation is here: [`backup`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'bk') and [`writebackup`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'writebackup').

For the question (my emphasis)

> What does `nowritebackup` **actually** do?

You can use [inotify](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to find out.  Make a test dir and save the settings you specified above as a test vimrc file, then write a file to that test directory and watch the output of inotify.  Like this:

first terminal window

```
mkdir test-dir
cat > test-dir/vimrc <<EOF
set nobackup
set writebackup " Enabled!
set noswapfile
set noundofile
EOF
inotifywait -m -r test-dir
```

second terminal window

```
vim test-dir/foo
:w
```

For me the output looks like this:

```
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
test-dir/ OPEN foo
test-dir/ CREATE foo~
test-dir/ OPEN foo~
test-dir/ ATTRIB foo~
test-dir/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE foo~
test-dir/ ATTRIB foo~
test-dir/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE foo
test-dir/ OPEN foo
test-dir/ MODIFY foo
test-dir/ ATTRIB foo
test-dir/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE foo
test-dir/ DELETE foo~
```